# Adding multiple values to array from an API and avoiding "undefined" error

Tags: javascript, undefined, javascript-objects

I am using the GoogleBooks API for a small side project and am running into a small issue. The problem is that sometimes the data is not uniform -- in that thumbnail images will be missing or author info will be missing. When the script runs to "add" a searched element to a database, it returns an error because one of the values will return undefined. Perhaps an example will make this more clear:

```
let volumeInfo = response.items[i].volumeInfo
    var book = {
        title: volumeInfo.title, 
        authors: volumeInfo.authors[0], 
        selfLink: response.items[i].selfLink
        cover: volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail
    }
```

For instance, an error I occasionally get is that "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined: for one of the results. A fix that I've found to work is the following:

```
var book = {
     title: volumeInfo.title, 
     authors: volumeInfo.authors[0], 
     selfLink: response.items[i].selfLink
     }
  if(volumeInfo.authors === undefined){
     book.authors = "null"
  }
  else{
     book.authors = volumeInfo.authors[0]
  }
  if(volumeInfo.imageLinks === undefined){
     book.cover = "null" 
  } else {
     book.cover = volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail
  }
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this without having to write "if" statements for all the elements I want to make an object from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) with [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

```
var book = {
  title: volumeInfo.title,
  authors: volumeInfo.authors?[0] ?? 'null',
  selfLink: response.items[i].selfLink,
  cover: volumeInfo.imageLinks?.thumbnail ?? 'null',
}
```

If you don't need the `'null'` string exactly, and just want to put a value there that indicates nothing was found, you can remove the `??` to have the values default to `undefined` when there's no such property, it'll make the code a bit shorter:

```
var book = {
  title: volumeInfo.title,
  authors: volumeInfo.authors?[0],
  selfLink: response.items[i].selfLink,
  cover: volumeInfo.imageLinks?.thumbnail,
}
```

Note that this is *pretty new* syntax. If you're going to put this code on a public website for general consumption, and you have a decently-sized, reasonably professional project, make sure [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) transpiles your code down to ES5 (or ES6) for production, so that older browsers can understand it.

Otherwise, you can do the undefined tests manually. To translate the last snippet to ES5:

```
var book = {
  title: volumeInfo.title,
  authors: volumeInfo.authors ? volumeInfo.authors[0] : undefined,
  selfLink: response.items[i].selfLink,
  cover: volumeInfo.imageLinks ? volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail : undefined
}
```

It's a bit verbose - I'd prefer Babel, hopefully you're already using it.

Comment: Thank you! Optional chaining is beautiful.